# Reporting the number of times IPs change value during program execution

Tags: machine-instruction

Can software be written (for some specific programming language, platform, etc.) that will inform a user of exactly how many times the relevant *machine-level instruction pointers* change value during the execution of a program? Is such software already available?

Comment: Are you basically looking to measure how many instructions are executed?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Yes, or rather counting "instruction-executions" -- i.e., it's not the number of instructions, but the number of times they are executed, in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, at least on many processors.  The key is the use of [*hardware performance counters*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter).

I'm not sure if there's a good API for accessing these.  But tools such as [*OProfile*](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) can do this kind of performance monitoring for you.